# how to create Json payload with no value assigned for the specific field?

Tags: json, model, jackson, fasterxml

If I want to create Json payload as below using `fasterxml.jackson`, what do I have to do?

```
{
    "email":
}
```

And this is how my model class look like:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

import java.io.Serializable;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "email" })
public class ApiRequest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;

    public ApiRequest() {
    }

    /**
     * @param email
     */
    public ApiRequest(String email) {
        this.email = email.equalsIgnoreCase("null") ? null : email;
    }

    @JsonProperty("email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @JsonProperty("email")
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email.equalsIgnoreCase("null") ? null : email;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The sample `{email: }` is invalid JSON. Everything must have a value in JSON. `{email: ''}, {email: null}, {email: false}` are all OK.

Comment: Yeah I got that but would like to know if there is any way to build payload like what I mentioned above?